# How to replicate UISearchBar scrolling behavior in Notes.app?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, uisearchbar

When you scroll a tableView down (*Notes.app*), the search bar stays fixed to top, but when you scroll a tableView up, the search bar is hidden. That's what I want.

Looking at scroll indicator it appears that UISearchBar is a subview of a table's scroll view. But if I add a search bar to a tableView in Interface Builder, then it always scrolls attached to a tableView just like a regular row.

Comment: any code we can see or test in are app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the table view, put a blank transparent UIView (`searchBarPlaceholderView`) into the tableHeaderView slot, that has exactly the dimensions of a UISearchBar. Then add the UISearchBar (`searchBar`) to the top-level view.

Then, in your table view delegate, add

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect sbFrame = searchBar.frame;
    sbFrame.origin.y = searchBarPlaceholderView.frame.origin.y - scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    // it cannot move from the top of the screen
    if (sbFrame.origin.y > 0) {
        sbFrame.origin.y = 0;
    }

    searchBar.frame = sbFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the default behaviour. You just have to drop the bar in the first header of the table (I guess it's the section 0).

However I just created a new application with an UITableViewController and, through the Interface Builder, I dropped the UISearchBar in the upper side of the tableView and it behaves just like the Notes.app application.

Comment: No, it's not, at least for me. Try to drag the table downwards - the search bar will follow it all the way down. In the Notes.app search bar stays attached to the top.

Comment: Oh, now I got that. By looking at Notes.app it seems that the searchbar is not part of the table but it is rendered as it was (just when you scroll down/up).

Answer (score 1):

Add the search bar to the table view in interface builder like normal (that is to say the search bar should be a subview of the table).

Then implement this method in the delegate:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    UISearchBar *searchBar = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar;
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0) {
        searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, searchBar.frame.size.width, searchBar.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```